# How did all the passwords get in my login keyring?

Tags: security, password

In my Passwords and Keys application (Seahorse) I have a "login" keyring. Within that are a many keys. How did they get there? What application put them there? I use Chrome with Lastpass extension, would that do it?

Answer (score 2):

Seahorse is the tool to manage keys and passwords. ([See seahorse manual.](http://library.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/index-info.html.en))

For more see [this Ubuntu Forums thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1302342).

Comment: This does not answer my question.